# Finding objects that are not associated with another model using a join table in between

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Ruby on Rails app with ActiveRecord and Postgres database. I have this relation of two models with a join table in between, basically every user can like multiple movies:

```rb
class Movie
  has_many :user_movie_likes
  has_many :users, through: :user_movie_likes
end

class UserMovieLike
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :user_movie_likes
  has_many :movies, through: :user_movie_likes
end
```

Considering I have the user id, I can easily fetch all the movies that are liked by this user, something like:

```rb
  # movie.rb
  scope :liked, ->(user_id) { joins(:user_movie_likes).where('user_movie_likes.user_id' => user_id) }
```

But I can't figure out how to do the inverse of this - all the movies that the given user didn't like yet. If I do `where.not('user_movie_likes.user_id' => user_id)`, it will still return movies that the user liked, because some other user liked them, and will not return movies that have no likes at all. For now I'm just plucking the ids from the `liked` scope and do `where.not(id: liked_ids)`, but I'm sure there is a good way to do it in one query. I found some other questions similar to this one on StackOverflow, but they were different cases, i.e. finding movies that have no likes etc.

Comment: Because there will be no entry in join table if like not made. We won't be able to fetch directly like this.

You will need to collect all movies and user liked movie and find the difference to know which movies were not liked

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
scope :liked, lambda { |user_id|
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_movie_likes ON user_movie_likes.movie_id = movies.id AND user_movie_likes.user_id = #{user_id}")
    .where('user_movie_likes.id IS NULL')
}
```